# How to estimate k of Weibull using method of moment in excel?

Tags: excel

I am using first moment and second moment to estimate k of Weibull only.
These are first moment and second moment of Weibull:

```
E(x) =λГ(1+1/k) -(1)
E(x^2)=λ^2Г(1+2/k) -(2)
```

Then (2)/(1)^2,

```
E(x^2)/E(x)^2=Г(1+2/k)/Г(1+1/k)^2
```

I have already calculate E(x^2)/E(x)^2=1.277 from my data.

```
1.277=Г(1+2/k)/Г(1+1/k)^2
```

I set

```
B1=(GAMMA(1+2/A1))/(GAMMA(1+1/A1))^2 as objective.
value is 1.277
variable is A1.
```

The solver can't solve it.

Comment: Mine solver can solve using GRG Nonlinear Solving method. `k` is `1.984873222`.

Comment: @lokWong you may want to mention this is a follow up from some of your earlier questions.

Comment: You also may want to consider asking over at the engineering section of stack exchange for a second opinion.

Comment: My solver cant solve it. I set GRG Nonlinear Solving method too.